# Facelets page changes in Netbeans not reflecting in browser, exclamation mark on file in project

Tags: jsf, netbeans, facelets

I have imported a JSF/Facelets project from SVN into Netbeans. Any change which I make in Facelets pages is not reflected in browser, even though I redeploy the project.

When I check my project's webapp folder in Netbeans, then I see an exclamation mark sign `!` on that Facelets file. Also in Netbeans it has turned into green and when I hover over it, it says locally modified.

It seems that it is ignoring my changes even though I save the page. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Update: I can see the pages inhttp://localhost:8080/portal-war/pages/displayMain.jsf . But when I go to this one "http://localhost:8080/portal/pages/displayMain.jsf" changes are not reflected. The database data is not showing up at the one which reflects the changes.

Comment: Thanks BalusC :) for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN concepts:

- The green symbol means the file is similar that the "last" version of the repository. This last time really means the last you have made a checkout or an update.
- The exclamation sign (!) means that the file has been locally modified and the changes are not commited. From another point of view, it means that you're working with that file and it will turn into green when you commit the changes.

Maybe you don't have enough permissions to write in the folder where the build results are set (this means, the folder with the WAR), so no matter how many times you try to deploy it, it will always deploy the last version you have checked out from the repository.

In the last case you can't write in that folder, you can use a dirty hack that consist on go to the folder, right click on it and uncheck the Read Only property, but don't commit this change! After that, try to rebuild your application and see if your changes are visible for you.